# Preposition + and + preposition

Tags: prepositions

As I was preparing for my exam, I stumped upon this sentence when reading a sample essay. However, since I have never used preposition + and + preposition, it would be great if anyone can tell me this sentence below sounds natural and its grammar is correct or not.

> Satisfaction is also increased by a sense of responsibility **for and loyalty to** a team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question **is Preposition + and + preposition**
(Can) anyone can tell me (if the) sentence below sounds natural and it's grammar is correct or not.

The easy answer is can you use them in two stand alone sentences?

> **Satisfaction is also increased by a sense of responsibility for, and loyalty to, a team.**

Satisfaction is also increased by a sense of responsibility for a team.

Satisfaction is also increased by a sense of  loyalty to a team.

**No the sentence does not sound natural** because it is not how you would normally talk. **Is the grammar correct? Yes** from the two stand alone sentences I was able to reproduce. However I am not sure if what the writer meant is what they have written, when they used **responsibility** **for**. 
Personally I would have written the following

**Satisfaction is also increased by both a sense of responsibility and loyalty towards a team.**

I believe the way the sentence is originally written leaves a bit of **ambiguity towards what the sense of responsibility is**. Is it a sense of he/she is the **responsible person** **for the team**( it's their Duty) . Or a sense of the ability to act correctly and make decisions that will be beneficial to the team. I believe the use of towards instead of for removes that ambiguity.

> Your responsibilities will be mainly administrative.
>
> The job carries a lot of responsibility
>
> **towards** preposition (RELATION) in relation to something or someone:[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/towards)

Answer (score 0):

Some commas would help:

> Satisfaction is also increased by a sense of responsibility for, and loyalty to, a team.

It means

> Satisfaction is increased by a sense of responsibility for a team. Also, Satisfaction is increased by a sense of loyalty to a team.

Comment: So the point is that without commas, the sentence is grammatically wrong?

Comment: @Floret Commas are in no way necessary. That's purely a subjective style. The grammar is fine without them.